Describing monoidal categories of positive-weight representations geometrically
Let $G=\mathbb{G}_m.$ The monoidal category $\mathcal{C}=\text{Rep}(G)$ of $G$-representations (also known as the category $\text{Gr}$ of graded vector spaces) can be written geometrically as $\mathcal{C}=\text{QCoh}(BG)$, which allows us to apply many tools from algebraic geometry to the study of this monoidal category. In particular, by a result of Ben-Zvi--Francis-Nadler, the trace $\text{Tr}(\mathcal{C})$ and center $Z(\mathcal{C})$ are both equivalent to the category of quasicoherent sheaves on the loop space $\mathcal{L}G = \mathbb{G}_m\times B\mathbb{G}_m.$
My question is: if I replace $\mathcal{C}=\text{Gr}$ by the category $\mathcal{C}':=\text{Gr}_{\geq 0}$ of positively-graded vector spaces (equivalently, positive-weight representations of $G$), is there any similar way of thinking about $\mathcal{C}'$ geometrically that allows me to understand its trace and center in terms of some kind of loop spaces? (Of course, in this particular case it's not so difficult to compute things about the category $\mathcal{C}'$ directly, using its structure as a monoidal category. But I would like to have a conceptual framework for organizing such calculations, and possibly generalizing them to more general algebraic stacks of the form $X/\mathbb{G}_m.$)

Those are representations of $\mathbb{G}_m$ that extend to an act of the multiplicative monoid $\mathbb{A}^1$.

There is more about this in Koll’ar’s article on projectivity of  (coarse moduli spaces of) complete moduli (Artin) stacks.  He proposes a notion for “positive” representations that should play an analogous role to ample locally free sheaves.

Thanks. Yes, maybe I should have asked, "what features of the theory of stacks persist if one allow stabilizers to be monoids rather than groups?" I assume that it's still possible to make sense of many results, but I haven't been able to find much written about this.

You can form a simplicial scheme for the monoid act, so it might be best to shift to the category of simplicial schemes instead of stacks.
